# Help. Tried to return phone to stock. Now only see LG logo. When trying to power down it just restarts. Cannot boot to recovery

Tags: unbricking, lg-g2

However, If I hold the power button to power it off and then hold off and down it turns on for a split second and then off permanently.

Comment: What exact steps did you follow to cause this problem? And what's your question?

Comment: I used this guide: http://theunlockr.com/2013/11/01/unroot-lg-g2-versions-video/ at IV, 10 I got stuck. I think that I might have not selected " Republic of Korea" as stated in step 8. My goal now is to somehow make my phone useable again. Thanks for you help.